# Ruby on Rails - Titleize Exceptions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model called Organizations that contains fields for its address. In the model I have the statement `before_save { self.address_line_1 = address_line_1.titleize }` and just realized this is changing addresses with PO Box to Po Box.

Another example: I also have a standard Users model with first name/last name. Titleize will change a person's first name from TJ to Tj. Or, if their last name is hyphenated it will go from Smith-Jones to Smith Jones.

With the PO box I would know the exception ahead of time, but not for user's names. Is there any way to allow for these exceptions at all while still having the core titlsize functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend trying to avoid changing the semantics of `titlelize`, though, to avoid issues later when you might expect it, in another part of the same application, to do what it's really intended to do. Since you're looking for some fairly specialized functionality for `titleize` I'd create a new, similar method which you could monkey patch into the `String` class, as above, called something like, `abook_titleize` (address book titleize):

```
class String
  def abook_titleize
    if allow_titleize(self)
      titleize
    else
      # Check for other behaviors, such as if "self" is all consonants
      # or if self is found in a predetermined list of acronyms,
      # perhaps return self.upcase
      self.upcase
    end
  end

private
  def allow_titleize(s)
    # Write some code here that determines if you want this string
    # to be titleized and return true if so, otherwise false
  end
end
```

Or something like that. You could make this as simple or as elaborate as you wish. If you really want to change `titleize` bahavior itself (again, I wouldn't recommend), then:

```
class String
  :alias_method :old_titleize, :titleize

  def titleize
    if allow_titleize(self)
      old_titleize
    else
    ...
```